# Child graphics item not receiving any event at all

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

There is a parent child relationship between two items. The child item which is a QGraphicsPixmapItem(image) was receiving all the events independently when rendered on the scene. But when I make a QGraphicsLineItem as its parent and rendered the image wrt parent item, I am unable to receive any event for the child. Please help, why is it happening?

My image item has events like hoverEnterEvent(), hoverLeaveEvent(), mouseMoveEvent() etc. Should all the events which are implemented in child item have a definition in parent too?
My parent does not have hoverEnterEvent() & hoverLeaveEvent(). I have also installed event filter on the child item. The parent item should receive all the events but it is not receiving any event at all. The important point to note is that I have rendered the image item wrt parent coordinate system. does it impact in any way. Please find the attached image.

[image: Image showing parent line item and child person image item]

Please find the child image item code below:

```
PersonSizeGraphicsItem::PersonSizeGraphicsItem(const QPixmap &pixmap, QGraphicsItem* parent_graphics_item, QGraphicsScene *scene)
    :QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap, parent_graphics_item, scene),
    parent_item(parent_graphics_item)
{
    this->setParentItem(parent_item);

    this->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
    this->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
    this->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges, true);
    this->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable, true);
    this->setFocus(Qt::MouseFocusReason);
    this->setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    //this->setScale(0.5);

    rect_left_condition = false;
    rect_right_condition = false;
    rect_top_condition = false;
    rect_bottom_condition = false;
    rect_resize_occurred = false;

    this->source_image = this->pixmap().toImage();

    image_rect = QRect();
    initializeImageRect();

}

PersonSizeGraphicsItem::~PersonSizeGraphicsItem()
{

}

int PersonSizeGraphicsItem::type() const
{
    return item_type;
}

void PersonSizeGraphicsItem::initializeImageRect()
{
    update();
}

void PersonSizeGraphicsItem::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
    const QPointF event_scene_pos = event->scenePos();
    QPolygonF poly_rect = this->mapToParent(this->boundingRect());
    qreal width = poly_rect.boundingRect().width();
    qreal height = poly_rect.boundingRect().height();

    // coordinates of item's bounding rect in scene coorinates.
    QPointF _p1 =  poly_rect.boundingRect().topLeft();      // (X,Y)
    QPointF _p2 =  poly_rect.boundingRect().topRight();     // (X + width,Y)
    QPointF _p3 =  poly_rect.boundingRect().bottomRight();  //(X+width, Y+height) 
    QPointF _p4 =  poly_rect.boundingRect().bottomLeft();   //(X,Y+ height) 

    rect_left_condition = ( event_scene_pos.x() > ( _p1.x() - 5 )  &&  event_scene_pos.x() < ( _p1.x() + 5 ) );
    rect_right_condition = ( event_scene_pos.x() > ( _p3.x() - 5  )  &&  event_scene_pos.x() < ( _p3.x() + 5 ) );

    rect_top_condition = ( event_scene_pos.y() > ( _p1.y() - 5 )  &&  event_scene_pos.y() < ( _p1.y() + 5 ) );
    rect_bottom_condition = ( event_scene_pos.y() > ( _p3.y() - 5 )  &&  event_scene_pos.y() < ( _p3.y() + 5 ) );


    if(  rect_left_condition || rect_right_condition )
    {
        this->setCursor(Qt::SizeHorCursor);
        return;
    }

    if(  rect_top_condition || rect_bottom_condition )
    {
        this->setCursor(Qt::SizeVerCursor);
        return;
    }

}

void PersonSizeGraphicsItem::hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
    const QPointF event_scene_pos = event->scenePos();

    QPolygonF poly_rect = this->mapToParent(this->boundingRect());
    qreal width = poly_rect.boundingRect().width();
    qreal height = poly_rect.boundingRect().height();

    // coordinates of item's bounding rect in scene coorinates.
    QPointF _p1 =  poly_rect.boundingRect().topLeft();      // (X,Y)
    QPointF _p2 =  poly_rect.boundingRect().topRight();     // (X + width,Y)
    QPointF _p3 =  poly_rect.boundingRect().bottomRight();  //(X+width, Y+height) 
    QPointF _p4 =  poly_rect.boundingRect().bottomLeft();   //(X,Y+ height) 

    bool horizontal_condition =  (event_scene_pos.x() > ( _p1.x()+ 8))  && (event_scene_pos.x() < (_p3.x() -8) );
    bool vertical_condition =   (event_scene_pos.y() > ( _p1.y()+ 8))  && (event_scene_pos.y() < (_p3.y() -8) );

    if( horizontal_condition && vertical_condition )
    {
        this->setCursor(Qt::SizeAllCursor);
    }

}

void PersonSizeGraphicsItem::hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
    this->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);

    rect_left_condition = false;
    rect_right_condition = false;
    rect_top_condition = false;
    rect_bottom_condition = false;

    QGraphicsItem::hoverLeaveEvent(event);
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Purpose: method called when mouse is pressed on the graphics item                              */
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
void PersonSizeGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if( this->cursor().shape() == Qt::SizeAllCursor )
    {
        QMimeData * mimeData = new QMimeData;
        PersonSizeGraphicsItem * item = this;
        QByteArray byteArray(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&item),sizeof(PersonSizeGraphicsItem*));
        mimeData->setData("Item",byteArray);

        // start the event
        QDrag * drag = new QDrag(event->widget());
        drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
        drag->exec();
    //  dragStart = event->pos();
        event->accept();
    }

}

void PersonSizeGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    const QPointF event_pos = event->pos();
    const QPointF event_scene_pos = event->scenePos();

    QPoint current_top_left = image_rect.topLeft();
    QPoint current_bottom_right = image_rect.bottomRight();

    if((event->scenePos().x() > this->scene()->width()) || (event->scenePos().y() > this->scene()->height())
        || (event->scenePos().x() < 0) || (event->scenePos().y() < 0) )
    {
        return;
    }

    if( this->cursor().shape() == Qt::SizeHorCursor )
    {
        if(rect_right_condition)
        {

            image_rect = QRect( current_top_left, QPoint( event->pos().x(), current_bottom_right.y()) );

            if( image_rect.width() <=8 || image_rect.height() <=24 )
            {
                return;
            }

            rect_resize_occurred = true;
        }

        if(rect_left_condition)
        {
            //image_rect = QRect( QPoint(event_pos.x(), 0), current_bottom_right );

            image_rect = QRect( QPoint(event_pos.x(), current_top_left.y()), current_bottom_right );

            if( image_rect.width() <=8 || image_rect.height() <=24 )
            {
                return;
            }
            rect_resize_occurred = true;


        }

    }

    if( this->cursor().shape() == Qt::SizeVerCursor )
    {
        if(rect_bottom_condition)
        {
            image_rect = QRect(current_top_left, QPoint(current_bottom_right.x(), event->pos().y()));

            if( image_rect.width() <=8 || image_rect.height() <=24 )
            {
                return;
            }

            rect_resize_occurred = true;
        }

        if(rect_top_condition)
        {
                image_rect = QRect(QPoint(current_top_left.x(), event_pos.y()), current_bottom_right);

            if( image_rect.width() <=8 || image_rect.height() <=24 )
            {
                return;
            }

        /*  QPoint new_top_left = image_rect.topLeft();
            QPointF mapped_topLeft = mapToParent(QPointF(new_top_left.x(),new_top_left.y()));
            this->setPos(mapped_topLeft); */

            rect_resize_occurred = true;

        }
    }

    this->update();

}


void PersonSizeGraphicsItem::paint (QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{

    CustomGraphicsLineItem* parent_line_item = dynamic_cast<CustomGraphicsLineItem *>(parent_item);
    if(parent_line_item == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QLineF parent_line = parent_line_item->line();
    QLineF normal_vector_line = parent_line.normalVector();
    normal_vector_line.setLength(20.0);

    QPointF first_line_base_point = parent_line.pointAt(0.5);

    QPointF _p1 = first_line_base_point -(normal_vector_line.p1()-normal_vector_line.p2());
    QPointF _p2 = first_line_base_point +(normal_vector_line.p1()-normal_vector_line.p2());

    QLineF rect_line_one = normal_vector_line;
    rect_line_one.setP1(_p1);
    rect_line_one.setP2(_p2);


    qDebug() << "rect_line_one p1:" <<  rect_line_one.p1();
    qDebug() << "rect_line_one p2:" <<  rect_line_one.p2();


    QRectF image_rect( rect_line_one.p1(), QSize(30, 60));

    painter->drawImage(image_rect, source_image);

}



 QRectF PersonSizeGraphicsItem:: boundingRect() const
 {
    qreal extra = 0.0;

    QRect rect = image_rect;
    return QRectF(rect.topLeft(), QSizeF(rect.width(), rect.height()))
    .normalized()
    .adjusted(-extra, -extra, extra, extra);
 }

QPainterPath PersonSizeGraphicsItem::shape() const
 {
    const int adjustment = 0.0;
    QPainterPath path;
    QRectF rect = boundingRect();
    path.addRect(rect.adjusted(-adjustment, -adjustment, adjustment, adjustment));
    return path;
 }
```

Comment: Did you call this one? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setAcceptHoverEvents By default, events are not accepted. The parent item should not have an effect on which hover events the child receives.

Comment: yes I called setAcceptHoverEvents(true) in the child item constructor.The child item which is a image when rendered independently on the scene receives all the events. I am able to resize the image etc

Comment: are you able to see the attached image.

Comment: Yeah I can see the image. I don't have any other ideas why it should not work, though.

Comment: Showing code would really help here. When you implement functions such as mouseMoveEvent, are you calling the base class functions too? Also check if the item you think your mouse is over is the top item.

Comment: Merlin069 - I did not call the mouseMoveEvent() of base call at all. This code works well when I render the image item on the scene as stand alone item. I am able to resize the image perfectly. The issue came up, when i made this image item the child of the QGraphicsLineItem. As you can see the parent item is in selected state, I am displayinmg the image item wrt the parent item. Please check the paint() of the above code.

Comment: My huge concern is that the top left corner of image item rect is not set to (0,0).The image item is rendered in parent coordinate system. Does that imapact in any way? how do I check if the item the mouse is over is the top item? The parent line is in selected state, does it mean its the top item? the  line item is receiving the mousePressEvent() even if I click on the image item especially in the overlapped area.

Comment: The other important thing is that I have installed an event filter on the image item, the parent was watching it. But no event is entering sceneEventFilter() of parent item, when I hover my mouse on image item.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the image item is not the top most item. How do I keep making different items as topmost item on the scene? I should be able to switch b/w different items when I select them.

Comment: The image item is receiving the events if we remove the parent-child relationship b/w image item and the line item. In the above code line item is passed as the parent to image item. Can someone try and explain why making one graphics item parent of another blocks the events to child item?